# Is restricting endorsement using author's name compatible with GPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I would like to link a GPL project to another project with the following clause in [its license](https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/asdcplib/blob/master/COPYING):

> The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

Is this software compatible with GPL v2 or v3?

Comment: Probably, so long as you don't use the name of the author to endorse or promote products derived from the software without specific prior written permission.  Is the *rest* of the license compatible with the GPL?

Comment: Thanks, yes, the rest of the license is compatible

Comment: But, is this not adding an extra restriction ?

Comment: Is it your intention to use the name of the author to endorse or promote products derived from the software without specific prior written permission?

Comment: no, not at all. But someone else might want to do this

Comment: normally, I would be free to do this with a GPL license

Comment: not illegal to do this

Comment: They don't need to.  The purpose of the GPL is to provide *freedoms of software use,* not to use the author's name for marketing purposes.  It's not an unreasonable request.

Comment: if you move this discussion to the answer section, I can mark it answered

Comment: I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: yes, I understand. But, still, you provided an answer that makes sense

Comment: I honestly don't know if such a clause is considered "compatible" with the GPL or not.  But I don't believe that it matters.

Comment: by compatible, I mean that the non-gpl software can be distributed with the gpl software. For example, the original BSD license is not compatible.

Comment: Yes, the original BSD license is not compatible, for obscure reasons that I haven't bothered to comprehend.  It's entirely possible that the clause you cited is not compatible with the GPL.  But that doesn't mean that it's *not a license.*  It might mean that the clause is legally unenforceable.  But again, I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: What does the rest of the license of the other project look like?

Comment: Link to or show the other license already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [modified BSD license](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:BSD_3Clause) (also called BSD 3-Clause License) contains the exact same sentence:

> (3)The name of the author may not be used to
>       endorse or promote products derived from this software without
>       specific prior written permission.

The Free Software Foundation lists the [modified BSD license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#ModifiedBSD) as GPL compatible.